# How to select mine and my friends post

Tags: php, sql, select, mysqli, social-networking

I am trying to make a social network but I can't get around with this code. I am trying to make a timeline where user sees his and his friends' post. But this SQL statement gives me the error 'Operand should contain 1 column(s)'. What should I do? Is there anything wrong in my code? Or can you suggest some other ways? I am using both PHP and SQL.

Here is my Code:

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE userId = 15 OR userId LIKE (SELECT user_one,user_two FROM friends WHERE user_one = 15 OR user_two = 15)

Table 'friends'
--------------------------------------------------------
id   user_one  user_two
1    15        14
2    14        13
```

Comment: Your subselect must SELECT only **ONE** column, moreover you should use  **IN** instead of **LIKE**.

Comment: post your `friends` table example columns and values

Comment: Still not working

Comment: what is still not working? have you modified the subselect code?

Comment: Question has already been answered and it is working... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`like` doesn't take a subquery - you probably meant to use the `in` operator. `in` takes a subquery with one column though. Using the `union all` operator may help you get all the results in the same column:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   posts
WHERE  userId = 15 OR userId IN (SELECT user_one FROM friends WHERE user_two = 15
                                 UNION ALL
                                 SELECT user_two FROM friends WHERE user_one = 15)
```